# Should ANSI C function definition be placed inside header (.h) or source (.c) file?

Tags: c, definition

What are advantages and disadvantages of both approaches?

### Source vs. header implementation

#### Function definition inside source file

Header file sourcefunction.h contains declaration only.

```
#ifndef SOURCEFUNCTION_H
#define SOURCEFUNCTION_H

void sourcefunction(void);

#endif // SOURCEFUNCTION_H
```

Source file sourcefunction.c contains definition

```
#include "sourcefunction.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void sourcefunction(void) { printf(" My body is in a source file\n"); }
```

#### Function definition inside header file

Header file headerfunction.h contains definition which is the declaration at the same time.

```
#ifndef HEADERFUNCTION_H
#define HEADERFUNCTION_H

#include <stdio.h>
void headerfunction(void) { printf(" My body is in a header file\n"); }

#endif // HEADERFUNCTION_H
```

No source file is needed.

#### Consumer

File main.c

```
#include "sourcefunction.h"
#include "headerfunction.h"

int main(void) {
    sourcefunction();
    headerfunction();
    return 0;
}
```

### Why compile many source files?

We have to compile all source files and remember about them during linking.

```
gcc -c sourcefunction.c
gcc -c main.c
gcc main.o sourcefunction.o
```

`Make` can handle file managing but why even bother?

### Is separation of interface and implementation always an issue?

It is obvious reason for big projects and teamwork. The designer specifies the interface. The programmers implement functionality.

What about smaller projects and non-formal approach?

### Is removing definition from header files always preventing from linker errors?

Let's assume my program is using another *module* that defines the function with the same name `sourcefunction()`.

```
#include "sourcefunction.h"
#include "sourcefunction1.h"
#include "headerfunction.h"

int main(void) {  
  headerfunction();
  sourcefunction();
  return 0;
}
```

#### Different function interface

File `sourcefunction1.h`

```
#ifndef SOURCEFUNCTION1_H
#define SOURCEFUNCTION1_H

int sourcefunction(void);

#endif // SOURCEFUNCTION1_H
```

File `sourcefunction1.c`

```
#include "sourcefunction1.h"
#include <stdio.h>
int sourcefunction(void) { int a = 5;  return a; }
```

By compiling main.c, I get a **nice** compiler error
`sourcefunction1.h:4:5: error: conflicting types for 'sourcefunction'`
showing me the location of error.

#### Same function interface

File `sourcefunction1.h`

```
#ifndef SOURCEFUNCTION1_H
#define SOURCEFUNCTION1_H

void sourcefunction(void);

#endif // SOURCEFUNCTION1_H
```

File `sourcefunction1.c`

```
#include "sourcefunction1.h"
#include <stdio.h>
void sourcefunction(void) { int a = 5;  printf("%d",a); }
```

Compiler does not mind multiple declarations. I get **ugly** linker error.

### Can header implementation serve as library?

jschultz410 says 
*If you are writing a library and all your function definitions are in headers, then other people who do segment their development into multiple translation units will get multiple definitions of your functions if they are needed in multiple translation units*

Lets' have
File consumer1.c

```
#include "headerfunction.h"
void consume1(void) { headerfunction(); }
```

File consumer2.c

```
#include "headerfunction.h"
void consume2(void) { headerfunction();  headerfunction();}
```

File twoConsumers.c

```
extern void consume1(void);
extern void consume2(void);
int main(void) {
    consume1();
    consume2();
    return 0;
}
```

Let's compile sources.

```
gcc -c consumer1.c
gcc -c consumer2.c
gcc -c twoConsumers.c
```

So far, so good. Now, linking.

```
gcc consumer1.o consumer2.o twoConsumers.o
```

Linker error: `multiple definition of 'headerfunction'`, of course.

But I can make my library function `static`.
File headerfunction.h, afterwards.

```
#ifndef HEADERFUNCTION_H
#define HEADERFUNCTION_H

#include <stdio.h>
static void headerfunction(void) { printf(" My body is in a header file\n"); }

#endif // HEADERFUNCTION_H
```

It hides the definition from other translation units.

Comment: first off, linker errors. then, google "modularity".

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant **1.** Linker errors happen also when you have 2 declaration of the same function in different header&source files. **2.** The concept of modularity is important for big projects and teamwork.

Comment: No, linker errors happen when two definitions occur in two different files.  Like when you include the same definition in two places

Answer (score 1):

I shouldn't answer this, but I will.

1. This can create duplicate definitions unless you really only have a single .c file in your project (unwise). Even the header guards won't prevent files the headers from being included multiple times if those multiple times are with different .c files. When the .obj files are linked together, there will be conflicts.
2. If only the function declaration and not definition is in the header, then only changes to the interface (the function name, parameters or return type) require recompiling dependencies. However, if the entire definition is in the header, then any change to the function requires recompiling all .c and .h files that depend on it, which, in a larger project, can create a lot of unnecessary recompiling.
3. It's not the convention. Libraries will not use this convention, so you'll be stuck dealing with their header file structure. Other developers will not use this convention, so you can create confusion or annoyance there.

Comment: I can agree only with the *2.* and only during development, `Make` does not know about header changes and thinks .o is up-to-date. when the implementation is _stable_ it is no longer problem.

Comment: @ **3** In fact the library made me thinking about putting implementation in header. I've been able to use `Boost::lambda` _header-library_ with `MinGW` in no time. But I can not use `Boost::regex` because I could compile that library.

Comment: "Make does not know about header changes and thinks .o is up-to-date." You can make make aware of .h's too.  Look into `makedepend`.  @3 If you are writing a library and all your function definitions are in headers, then other people who do segment their development into multiple translation units will get multiple definitions of your functions if they are needed in multiple translation units.

Comment: The main advantage of having only one translation unit for your program is that it can make it easier for your compiler to figure out inlining optimizations.  OTOH, it makes all your file scope objects effectively global and they can clash now.  Regardless of that issue, the usual way to do that is to develop normally with .c's and .h's and then have one file that #include's all the .c's and .h's you want in a single translation unit.