# How to call function from other files like headers in C?

Tags: c, function, header-files

I'm trying to build a simple program that tells the user their Zodiac sign and life path number. The problem is even when given a wrong birth date it keeps writing the life path number. I am using Euclidean division exmp 12/02/1999

```
year 1999 = 1 + 9 + 9 + 9 = 28  2 + 8 = 10  1 + 0 = 1
```

I want to call this function from the main.c. How can I do that? thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
int year_verif(year,q3,ql,r,q2,q1,q4,xy,xt,xt2)
{
  printf("Enter your birth year\n");
  scanf("%d", &year);
  while (year <= 1920 || year >= 2020) {
    printf("Invalid Year of Birth \n");
    printf("Re-enter your birth year\n");
    scanf("%d", &year);
  }
    
  q1 = year / 1000;
  r = year % 1000;
  q2 = r / 100;
  r = r % 100;
  q3 = r / 10;
  r = r % 10;
  q4 = r;
  xy = q1 + q2 + q3 + q4;
    
  if (xy >= 10 )
  {
    xt = xy / 10;
    xt2 = xy % 10;
    xy = xt + xt2;
  }

  printf("year ""%d\n",xy);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ...). Take inspiration from *existing* open source C programs on [github](http://github.com/) or elsewhere, such as [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). Show some [mre] in your question, and see also [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Learn to use a debugger (such as [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) ... whose source code you could study for inspiration). Use perhaps also [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)

Comment: In 2020, code at least in C99. Read [this C11 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Your code is in ancient C (your `year_verif` definition won't compile today). Compile it with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g -std=c11` if using a recent GCC (e.g. enable all warnings and debug info)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Re “your `year_verif` definition won't compile today”: Clang, GCC, and MSVC all compile it, with default options.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: What is a minimal reproducible example of “I do not know how to call a function from another file?” Do you want an empty file named `main.c`, or perhaps a file named `main.c` with an `int main(void) {}` in it with no code inside it? What purpose would that serve? Minimal reproducible examples are for questions asking to debug existing code, not for questions asking how to write code that does not exist. How would running a debugger on an empty `main` function educate a student about how to call a function in another file?

Comment: @EricPostpishil: I meant : won't compile *cleanly* with `-std=c11` - it gives 9 warnings with GCC 10 invoked as `gcc -c -Wall -std=c11 /tmp/oussama.c`. And regarding education: there are books and courses.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: The fact there are books and courses is not an answer to how running a debugger on an empty `main` function would educate a student. My point is you came down like a hammer on a submitter, requesting inapplicable things and giving inapplicable advice. That served to show disdain, not to help or educate.

Comment: Why do you include q1, q2, q3, q4, r, xy, xt, etc. as parameters to the function if their values are calculated **inside** the function?  as such, they should not be parameters, but local variables, and should be declared **inside** the function's body, as with `int q1, q2, q3, q4, r, xy, xy, etc;`  and so, you don't need to pass them from `main()`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I'm afraid I had no problems compiling (today, indeed I did it just a few hours ago) that code today.  Don't say it doesn't compile today. Say it doesn't compile if you put in force the last published standard.  But GCC and CLANG compile that code without any problem.  I agree this is ancient style code, but it does compile and it is necessary because still there's code out there, that requires old legacy K&R style.  Nobody would make the effort of maintaining old legacy style if there was no code to compile it.

Comment: and indeed it compiled _cleanly_, with no warning or error at all.  It is not recommended using that style, or using that syntax in new projects today, but that's perfect C, like there was one time people spoke old english.

Comment: I'm afraid the only C @BasileStarynkevitch understands is C11 or later.  Before 2011 there was no such C language.

Comment: @LuisColorado. No, my first C programs have been written on a Sun3/160 in 1986. There have been proprietary and related to my PhD thesis.

Comment: Ok, but we are not here to measure our...  curricula? I'm afraid if your assertion is true then I still have more experience than you with C, so your assertion doesn't impress me at all (if that was your intention).  I started programming in C in 1979, and before I was proficient in Pascal and Basic (and z80 machine language). You should not say that that code will not compile today.  Probably we are the same age, based on what you say.  Please, acept my apologies if I have said something not of your like, but I'll not continue with this.

Answer (score 1):

*"I want to call this function from the main.c."*

Jump to bottom if you simply want the answer to this question.  Otherwise, following are some observations and suggestions...

As mentioned in comments under your question, some implementations of the C standard (eg. Clang, GCC, and MSVC) allow functions declared with identifier lists, such as this

```
int year_verif(year,q3,ql,r,q2,q1,q4,xy,xt,xt2)
```

...but always expect explicit *typed* declarations before use.  For example, called in `main()`:

```
int main(void)
{
    int year = 0;
    int q3 = 0;
    int ql = 0;//note - que ell
    int r = 0;
    int q2 = 0;
    int q1 = 0;// note que one
    int q4 = 0;
    int xy = 0;
    int xt = 0;
    int xt2 = 0;
    year_verif(year,q3,ql,r,q2,q1,q4,xy,xt,xt2);
```

(Your original code is missing this step and needs to be added.)

Although *identifier lists* are accommodated by the standard, it is more common and acceptable to use *parameter type lists* ([differences are discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18820829/645128)) in the function argument list,

```
int year_verif(int year,int q3,int ql,int r,int q2,int q1,int q4,int xy,int xt,int xt2);
```

***If*** you need updated values of variables to be passed back to the calling function (otherwise ignore this section.), one other important addition is needed before any of these variables can be used to pass back results of the work done in the function.  The changed value of a variable can only be returned via a pointer argument, as shown in the following adaptation of the original prototype:

```
int year_verif(int *year,int *q3,int *ql,int *r,int &q2,int *q1,int *q4,int *xy,int *xt,int *xt2);
```

Now when called in `main()` the *address of* (`&`) each argument will be passed so that the updated values can be passed back:

```
year_verif(&year,&q3,&ql,&r,&q2,&q1,&q4,&xy,&xt,&xt2);
```

One more suggestion however, since there are so many arguments, it would be more readable and otherwise manageable to collect all arguments into one construct, then pass
that single object:

```
typedef struct {
   int year;
   int q3;
   int ql;//note - que ell
   int r;
   int q2;
   int q1;//note - que one
   int q4;
   int xy;
   int xt;
   int xt2;
}date_s;
```

Then your function prototype becomes:

```
int year_verif(date_s *date)
{
    //...
}
```

this can be called in main like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    ...
    date_s date = {0};
    int ret = year_verif(&date);
    ...
```

A quick comment about your title question, i.e.:

> *"How to call function from other files like headers in C?"*

This is possible, but architecturally really not a good idea, as laid out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28952426/645128) to a similar question.

> *"How to call a function residing in one .c file from a function  (eg. `main()`) residing in another file"*:

Say your function (no matter what form it has taken.) is defined in a file called date.c

> *date.c*

```
...
int year_verif(date_s *date)
{
    ...
}
```

Place the prototype for the function:  `int year_verif(date_s *date);` into a header file named for example date.h

> *date.h*

```
int year_verif(date_s *date);
```

Then, in `main.c`, add the line: `#include "data.h"` along with other header files at the top of the `main.c` file:

> *main.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "date.h"
```

Now the function can be called just as shown above.

Comment: hmmmm... if he is calculating the values **inside** the function, then the variables `q1, q2, ...` should not be parameters at all... The PO is only using those values to find the final number he prints, so there's no need for them to be parameters, but just local variables to `year_verif()` which shoul only use one parameter (the `year`).

Comment: @LuisColorado - Good point.  Actually there is not a single parameter, as written, that is _needed_ to produce an argument for `printf()`.  `year` is read in with `scanf`, the rest are derived.  However, OP _does_ show a function with these parameters, then asks how to call it from a function.  The  because of this my main focus was to point out two omissions, 1 explicit typing of variables in function prototype, the other (assuming OP really wants to have access to derived values of parameters.) offered an alternative using pointers to struct.

Comment: see my answer.... I think this is what he tries to do.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one parameter in your function.  Also, you need to declare your local variables and parameters (you can do the way you are doing, but that's legacy code that should be avoided for new programs, just to compile very old code)  Here is a possible way of what you are trying to do, to compute the verification year number of the passed value.  I think this is what you are trying to do in your program, but I'm  not sure.  Anyway, it seems to work, and illustrates you how you can define two functions in a single compilation unit, and call `year_verif()` from `main()` and passing it **one** parameter (the year value, computed in `main()`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int year_verif(int yr)
{

  int q1 = yr / 1000;
  int r = yr % 1000;
  int q2 = r / 100;
  r = r % 100;
  int q3 = r / 10;
  r = r % 10;
  int q4 = r;
  int xy = q1 + q2 + q3 + q4;

  if (xy >= 10 )
  {
    int xt = xy / 10;
    int xt2 = xy % 10;
    xy = xt + xt2;
  }

  return xy;

}

int main(void)
{
  printf("Enter your birth year\n");
  int year;
  int res = scanf("%d", &year); /* scanf returns the number of matched
                                 * parameters, so it should be 1 on
                                 * good reading. */
  while (res == 1 && (year <= 1920 || year >= 2020)) {
    printf("Invalid Year of Birth \n");
    printf("Re-enter your birth year\n");
    res = scanf("%d", &year);
  }
  if (res == 1)
    printf("year_verif(%d) => %d\n", year, year_verif(year));
  return 0;
}
```

It compiles and runs like this:

```
$ a.out
Enter your birth year
13600
Invalid Year of Birth 
Re-enter your birth year
142
Invalid Year of Birth 
Re-enter your birth year
1962
year_verif(1962) => 9
$ _
```